# How to synchronize phone contacts with xmpp server contacts?

Tags: iphone, xmppframework

Hi i am new to stackoverflow. I am developing an xmpp client application for iphone using xmppframework. I have done the chat part. Now i want to synchonize the iphone contacts and xmpp server contacts. For this i want to check whether this contact is available in xmpp server. Please help me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For synchronizing contacts with xmpp server use XEP extension-0055 which is a jabber search plugin. Refer this link.

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0055.html

Comment: Could you throw more light on how exactly this could be achieved with mongooseim?

Comment: @VigneshPT  .. I am trying Chat App. Framework gettin Contacts from server automatically. How to Store our phone book contacts into Ejabbered Server.? Any idea. Am Doin iOS app..